# How to include css file for a specific view in FuelCMS

Tags: php, css, fuelcms

How can I include a css file only for a specific view in FuelCMS? Something along the lines of:

```
if (!empty($is_blog)):
    echo css('blog').css($css);
endif;
```

If this is possible, where should I set the `$is_blog` variable so that it's recognized in the `header.php` block?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is with page variables. In the *fuel/application/views/_variables* directory, there is a **global.php** file that you can add overrides the on a page-by-page basis:

```
$vars['css'] = array('global.css');
$pages['blog|blog/(:any)']['css'] = array('global.css', 'blog.css');
```

You can then output the `$css` variable as you normally would in a view, block, or layout which will only load the override on the specified pages.

http://docs.getfuelcms.com/general/pages-variables